# Python Checking 4 digits

Tags: python

```
import string
import math
def fourDigit():
    num = raw_input("Enter a 4 digit number: ")
    if (len(num) == 4 and string.digits == True):
        some = int(int(val[1]) + int(val[3]))
        print("The sum of the 1st and second term is: ")
    else:
       print("Error!")
```

So in this function I specified that the number must be 4 digits and the string must have digits. Even if i enter 1234 it prints error.

Comment: what is the variable `val`, first off? Also, if you are adding two `int`s, the result will be an int. The line which uses an ill-defined variable, `some = int(int(val[1]) + int(val[3]))`, casts an int to an int which is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string.digits` is a string, `"0123456789"`. `string.digits == True` is nonsensical, and guaranteed to always return `False`.

If you're trying to make sure all the characters entered are numeric, do:

```
if len(num) == 4 and num.isdigit():
```

If you really want to use `string.digits` for whatever reason, a slower approach that uses it correctly would be:

```
if len(num) == 4 and all(c in string.digits for c in num):
```

Comment: it still comes up as false

Comment: That works by disabling the test. You might want to reexamine your inputs; `print(repr(num))` should let you know if you actually got four digits or if there is additional contents in the `str` you're missing.